# How to add different rewrite rules to the 1 and 2 directory levels?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How is it possible to force the **trailing slash** only to the **1** directory level:

```
 http://example.com/dir1 -> http://example.com/dir1/
```

AND
to force the **.html** suffix to the **2** directory level

```
  http://example.com/dir1/dir2 or http://example.com/dir1/dir2/ -> 

  -> http://example.com/dir1/dir2.html
```

I tried these rules, but they seem don't work proper:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
 RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST}/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ [L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
 RewriteRule {HTTP_HOST}/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ [L]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Rule number 1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)(\.html?)?/?$ /$1/ [L]
# Rule number 2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Change the flags to `[R,L]` if you want the rewritten URLs to appear in the browser

Comment: Thank you, it works, but partly: on URLs like http://example.com/test.html it adds the slash on the end, so the URL becomes http://example.com/test.html// . But it should become from http://example.com/test.html -> http://example.com/test//

Comment: OK, wasn't clear from your question that's the behaviour you wanted. I've made an edit to the first rule, give that a go.

Comment: weird, the same effect: http://example.com/test.html -> http://example.com/test.html//

Comment: Yep, my bad, made another tiny edit a couple of mins ago - the addition of the `?` in the first capture group is required to stop the pattern being greedy